# Selenium not recognizing the xpath

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath

On Python 3.9 and Selenium 4.00

Hi there, I'm currently trying to automate downloading a few things on Chrome. I got the login part and navigating to the page down and it works properly. I'm having issues with the next part which is clicking "export" then "export as csv". I hover over the HTML source code and it highlights the buttons I need to press so I hit "copy XPath" but selenium won't press it and I get this error.

Edit: I cannot share the site as it is locked behind a login and it is not my login to give out; end of edit.

```
Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //*[@id="report_nav_menu"]/ul/li[2]/a"
```

Here's my code

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get('website')
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="report_nav_menu"]/ul/li[2]/a').click()
time.sleep(1)  # makes sure the page loads
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="report_nav_menu"]/ul/li[2]/ul/li[6]/a').click()
time.sleep(1000) # to keep the browser open
```

This the is HTML source code:

[Source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGggo.png)

The first highlight in the pic is for the Export button.

[Need to click this first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHozl.png)

The second highlight shows that it's for the CSV button.

[Need to click this second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOXQ2.png)

Comment: The error is saying that your xpath `//class[@elname="zc-navmenuEl/button[2]` is not correct. And the code you shared does not have this. Please check carefully where this exists?

Answer (score 0):

`//class[@elname="zc-navmenuEl/button[2]` seems to be an invalid XPath expression.
I can't see this locator used in the code you presented in the question.
Also you didn't share an URL of the page you are working with so I can't determine the correct element locator.

Comment: I realized I copied the wrong error message as I was trying multiple things. Have since updated what the error was.